# Detecting which URI a HTTP 302 is redirecting to in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am attempting to find out which URL a URI redirects to with use of a HTTP 302

E.g. I have a web page: http://www.example.com/pagenothere.php that redirects to http://www.google.com

I have used a method to attempt to retrieve the details, but I have been unable to get it to find the reponse code or the redirection url:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlString);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        request.Accept = "text/plain";

        MessageBox.Show("Response headers");
        MessageBox.Show("  Protocol version: " + response.ProtocolVersion);
        MessageBox.Show("  Status code: " + response.StatusCode);
        MessageBox.Show("  Status description: " + response.StatusDescription);
        MessageBox.Show("  Content encoding: " + response.ContentEncoding);
        MessageBox.Show("  Content length: " + response.ContentLength);
        MessageBox.Show("  Content type: " + response.ContentType);
        MessageBox.Show("  Last Modified: " + response.LastModified);
        MessageBox.Show("  Server: {0}", response.Server);
        MessageBox.Show("  Length using method: {0}\n", response.GetResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning AllowAutoRedirect off, which should allow you to see the redirect response.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx

Comment: Thomos Hi, instead of reponse.StatusCode returning "OK" it now returns "FOUND", I was assuming it would return "302"

Comment: HttpStatusCode.Found and HttpStatusCode.Redirect are both equivalent to 302.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx.

Comment: `if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found) redirectLocation = response.Headers["Location"];`

Answer (score 1):

Redirection location is returned in Location header of the response.

See 14.30 of http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: Thanks, but when response.StatusCode is returned it only comes out as "OK" - Also could you provide an example for your answer, as I can't seem to find a location property

Comment: Are you sure the response for the request is rediection then? OK would map to http status 200. Of course it might be that the content of the page then contains logic for loading another page, but that would require parsing the html content and looking for refresh directive from there, see for example http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: I used wget to confirm that is does send back 302 and tamper data

Comment: Then I would suggest checking the auto redirection  suggested in anothet answer.